# How to get the selected radio button's value with Prototype or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, prototypejs, radio-button

How can I get the value of the selected radio button using JQuery or Prototype?

Here is my form:

```
<label for="deliveryChoice">Courier&nbsp;<b>&pound;3.00</b></label>
<input type="radio" name="deliveryChoice" value="2.00" onchange="updateBasketTotals();" />
<label for="deliveryChoice">Royal Mail&nbsp;<b>&pound;2.80</b></label>
<input type="radio" name="deliveryChoice" value="2.00" onchange="updateBasketTotals();" />
```

The last 2 commands I tried were:

```
deliveryVal = Form.getInputs('deliveryProcessor','radio','deliveryChoice').find(function(radio) { return radio.checked; }).value;
deliveryVal = jQuery('[name="deliveryChoice"]:radio:checked').val();
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**

The radio buttons are created as a result of an ajax call after page load. Here is a link to a jsfiddle with it: [jsfiddle.net/4naqm](http://jsfiddle.net/4naqm)

Comment: Are you using jQuery and Prototype on the same page? If so, `$` is probably not the jQuery function.

Comment: I am using both, but JQuery.noConflict were I use JQuery

Comment: So that means you're actually using `jQuery(...)` and not `$(...)`? How about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: your second code should work, as Matt Ball said problem should be a conflict.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad, but neither lines work :/

Comment: And Matt Ball, here is one: http://jsfiddle.net/4naqm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var value = jQuery("input[name='deliveryChoice']:checked", yourForm).val();
```

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict(); alert(jQuery("input[name='deliveryChoice']:checked", "deliveryProcessor").val());` returns "undefined";

Comment: Replace "deliveryProcessor" with document.forms["deliveryProcessor"].

Answer (score 15):

Using Prototype you can get the value of selected radio by :

```
$$('input:checked[type=radio][name=deliveryChoice]')[0].value;
```

Hope this Helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: $('input:radio').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
}); returns a DOMException

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input:radio:checked").val()
```